# EventListeners not firing (even after including JavaScript at the end)

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

This is not a duplicate of ["Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?".](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element) I have a form that is supposed to trigger a bunch of events but none of the functions get called. I added a button just for the purpose of testing.

**The HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset ="utf-8" />
    <title>Sign in</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="passphrase.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <noscript>
        Javascript is disabled. Now redirecting.
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=passnojs.html"> 
    </noscript>
    Welcome.
    <form method="post" action="prolevel2.php" id="loginForm">
        <!--code snipped-->
        <br /><br /><input type="button" value="big ugly button" id="testing" />
    </form>
    <script src="verify.js"></script><!--this should work because it's after the HTML-->
</body>
</html>
```

**Included external JavaScript**

```
alert("begining")
document.getElementById('testing').addEventListener('onclick', display, false)
alert("here now")
function display()
{
    alert("now displaying")//doesn't work
}
```

"begining" and "here now" are displayed but "now displaying is not". There are no messages in the console. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use 'click' instead of 'onclick', and add semicolons ... at the end of all expressions!

Comment: [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/okulok/1/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
document.getElementById('testing').addEventListener('click', function(){alert("now displaying")}, false);
```

or

```
document.getElementById('testing').addEventListener('click',display, false);
```

Comment: There is no need to add anonymous function... `....('click', display...` will work.

Comment: Yes he only forgot to actually call the function he declared

Comment: How do you know when to drop the `on` prefix? Is it only used in inline event handlers?

Comment: this is the syntax for addEventListener.
if you give click event inline ,then you have to write onclick.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error, as others have mentioned. "onclick" should be "click". For default events, i prefer using the attribute instead of addEventListener, which throws a proper syntax error if entered incorrectly:

```
alert("begining")
document.getElementById('testing').onclick = display;
alert("here now")
function display()
{
    alert("now displaying");//doesn't work
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MaxPRafferty/N4qGB/